# How do I have the .NET framework parse a double empty xmlns element?

Tags: .net, xml-namespaces, soap-client

I have a webservice I am connecting to (ASMX) that for some reason spits out something that looks like this:

```
<someRecord Xmlns="" xmlns="">
  ...
</someRecord>
```

The parser seems to puke on the double empty xmlns in the SoapClient itself. Note the capitalization of the one element (which I can confirm with an ILSpy of their code that they are hard constructing this element).

How can I parse this programmatically without it blowing up? Do I need to interrupt the stream and kill the double xmlns myself? How would I do that ...